# What causes error in the poll() function, c++?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm fairly new to socket programming, and I'm trying to write a program that would get incoming tcp connections and manage them somehow. I can't figure out why the following code is giving me a "poll error":

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char *port;
struct pollfd connections[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
struct addrinfo addr_hints, *addr_result;
int ret, i;

for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; ++i) {
    connections[i].fd = -1;
    connections[i].events = POLLIN;
    connections[i].revents = 0;
}

port = "0";

memset(&addr_hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
addr_hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
addr_hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
addr_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
addr_hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &addr_hints, &addr_result);

connections[0].fd = socket(addr_result->ai_family, addr_result->ai_socktype, addr_result->ai_protocol);

if (connections[0].fd < 0) {
    cerr << "Socket error" << endl;
    return 0;
}

if (bind(connections[0].fd, addr_result->ai_addr, addr_result->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
    cerr << "Bind errror" << endl;
    return 0;
}

if (listen(connections[0].fd, 25) < 0) {
        cerr << "Listen error" << endl;
    return 0;
}

do {
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; ++i)
            connections[i].revents = 0;

    ret = poll(connections, MAX_CONNECTIONS, -1);

    if (ret < 0) {
        cerr << "Poll error" << endl;
        return 0;
    } else {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }

} while(true);
}
```

MAX_CONNECTIONS is a constant set to 10000. Connections[0] is supposed to be the descriptor on which i am listening to incoming connections. I set port to "0" because i want to pick a random port. It seems that the poll function fails immediately, yielding the message "Poll error" (so poll() was less than 0 basically). I've checked and after poll and bind connections[0] has a file descriptor. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, is it something with the getaddrinfo function?

Comment: When you get an error from a system call you need to check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to get the error code. You can use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string of the error.

Comment: I see. I did as you recommended and turns out it's a "Invalid argument" error. Is there some kind of limit on the size of the pollfd structure? I don't know what else could be wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your file descriptor array for poll is too large. The maximum size it can be is defined as RLIMIT_NOFILE. This is likely 1024 for your system. Reduce MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS to this value or less.

From the poll spec:

```
EINVAL The nfds value exceeds the RLIMIT_NOFILE value.
```

See more at: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html